Kubernetes readinessProbe initialDelaySeconds after startupProbe
I have a deployment with these probes defined:
startupProbe:
  failureThreshold: 40
  httpGet:
    path: /health
    port: 9080
    scheme: HTTP
  periodSeconds: 10
  successThreshold: 1
  timeoutSeconds: 5

readinessProbe:
  failureThreshold: 3
  httpGet:
    path: /health
    port: 9080
    scheme: HTTP
  initialDelaySeconds: 130
  periodSeconds: 5
  successThreshold: 1
  timeoutSeconds: 5

livenessProbe:
  failureThreshold: 8
  httpGet:
    path: /health
    port: 9080
    scheme: HTTP
  periodSeconds: 5
  successThreshold: 1
  timeoutSeconds: 5

I wanted a delay on readinessProbe so the pod won't be added immediately as an endpoint on the service after startupProbe succeeds so it won't receive traffic immediately.
Based on Kubernetes documentation:
If a startup probe is defined, liveness and readiness probe delays do not begin until the startup probe has succeeded. If the value of periodSeconds is greater than initialDelaySeconds then the initialDelaySeconds would be ignored. Defaults to 0 seconds. Minimum value is 0.
I expect the readinessProbe initialDelaySeconds to start counting after startuProbe has succeeded, but the startupProbe succeeds at like 30-35 seconds and readinessProbe is successful immediately at 130.
I expected the readiness to be successful at around 160ish seconds.
Why do you think this is happening or is this supposed to be a default behaviour
Describe events

Containers:
  application:
    Liveness:   http-get http://:9080/health delay=60s timeout=5s period=5s #success=1 #failure=8
    Readiness:  http-get http://:9080/health delay=100s timeout=5s period=5s #success=1 #failure=3
    Startup:    http-get http://:9080/health delay=0s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=40
    

Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Created           2m48s                  kubelet            Created container application
  Normal   Started           2m48s                  kubelet            Started container application
  Normal   Created           2m48s                  kubelet            Created container fluentd
  Normal   Started           2m48s                  kubelet            Started container fluentd
  Warning  Unhealthy         2m19s (x3 over 2m39s)  kubelet            Startup probe failed: Get "http://10.6.91.98:9080/health": dial tcp 10.6.91.98:9080: connect: connection refused



Could you provide the log output of kubectl describe <pod> with a pod that is at least 160 seconds old?

@JoaquínMuleiro I added the events on the question

Are you 100% certain you posted the latest version of the manifest? The line Readiness:  http-get http://:9080/health delay=100s timeout=5s period=5s #success=1 #failure=3 suggests that the readiness probe's initialDelaySeconds is 100.
